# Is there a way to assign linenumber do the bean in OpenCSV?

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

- I initially build the CsvToBean

```
    CsvToBean<> beans = new CsvToBeanBuilder<>(reader).withThrowExceptions(false).build();
```

- After I perform the parse.

```
    final List<> requestList = beans.parse();
```

- Finally I can go through the list of beans with a forEach.

```
    requestList.forEach(fileRow -> {
    // exception here... what is the original csv line number???
    })
```

If something goes wrong here, I need to be able to indicate the csv line number that caused
the error.

Is there any solution?
Thanks